# several instances of object on canvas

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, drawimage

I made this little script that makes an image bounce up and down (which is working fine).

Now I'm trying to add more images (more instances of that object) on my canvas, but for some reasons it's still showing only one.

If someone could spot what I'm missing, it would be appreciated.

```
var img = function() {

    this.props = {
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * W + 1),
        y: 50,

        radius: 40,

        // Velocity
        vy: 1,

        // angle
        angle: 0,
        direction: 1
    };

    var self = this;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(im, self.props.x, self.props.y);
    },

    this.update = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

        self.draw();

        self.props.y += self.props.vy;
        self.props.vy += gravity;

        if(self.props.y + self.props.radius > H) {
            self.props.y = H - self.props.radius;
            self.props.vy *= -bounceFactor;
            self.props.direction *= -1;
        }
    };

};

// my instances
var el = new img();
var el2 = new img();
var el3 = new img();

function main() {
    el.update();
    el2.update();
    el3.update();
}

setInterval(main, 1000/60);
```

Here's the full code: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HMAd4/5/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clear the while canvas for all cars, so only the last one can be shown.
Just clear once in your main() function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using single image instance in DOM ... your fiddle is using `src` from closure scope referring to single image instance.

EDIT: In your code here `im` isn't actually referring to something, but it is shared among all instances of `img()`.

Comment: That's because all the images have the same source. Nothing wrong about that.

Comment: But in your fiddle there is `src = document.getElementById('img')`, thus accessing the DOM element containing image rather than its source. I'm not that much familiar with canvas, but you have several instances sharing one data source. If that's okay, I'm fine ;)